# How to pass a component as a parameter of a procedure in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want to be able to use one procedure to center all the components on a form. This is the kind of thing I'm going for:

```
procedure TForm4.centerComponent(x: Tobject);
begin
x.Left := (Form4.ClientWidth - x.Width) div 2;
end;
```

I would only be passing built in components (memo, label, edit etc...)
I get the feeling this is either not possible or if it is its probably not best practice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easy, but you must be careful about terminology:

- A `TObject` is any Delphi object. It need not be a control. It doesn't even need to be something you can drop on a form.
- A `TComponent` is an object you can drop on a form. It might be a visual control (like a button, a label, or an edit box), or it might be a non-visual component (like a `TActionList`).
- A `TControl` is a visual control, like a button, a label, an edit box, or an animated analogue clock.

The above classes are ordered by inheritance.

So, you want a procedure that acts on `TControl`s in general:

```pascal
procedure Centre(AControl: TControl);
var
  Parent: TWinControl;
begin
  Parent := AControl.Parent;
  if Parent = nil then
    Exit;
  AControl.SetBounds(
    (Parent.ClientWidth - AControl.Width) div 2,
    (Parent.ClientHeight - AControl.Height) div 2,
    AControl.Width,
    AControl.Height
  );
end;
```

Every `TControl` has `Top`, `Left`, `Width`, and `Height` properties, as well as the `SetBounds` method, which we use above.

Notice that I centre the control in its parent window. (A control's `Top` and `Left` values are always relative to its parent.)

Now, there are two kinds of controls in Delphi:

- Controls that are actual Win32 windows (with HWNDs).
- Controls that are not actual Win32 windows.

Only the former kind of control can have child controls. These controls derive from `TWinControl`. That's the reason I declare `Parent` as a `TWinControl`. This is also the type of the `TControl.Parent` property.

## Some notes about your code

```
x.Left := (Form4.ClientWidth - x.Width) div 2;
```

Here there are two issues (except for `x: TObject` not having any `Width` or `Left` properties):

- `Form4` is *one particular* instance of the form class. It is much better to write `Self.ClientWidth` or simply `ClientWidth`, so you refer to the *current* instance of the form class.
- But even this is not good enough, because this only works if the form is the parent of `x`. `x` might well have a different parent. For instance, `x` might have a `TPanel` as its parent (the `TPanel`'s parent being the form).